# Assembly code meaning in gdb

Tags: gdb, itanium

Good day!
I have a core file, and I disassembled (using gdb) the method that
crashed and I was told that the the value assigned to **r44** below
causes the crash.

I am not well verse with assembly so I would like to ask what does
**0x480** offset mean and how to locate its value?/address? by using
the core file in gdb.

Is it safe to assume that **0x480** is located in the function
**MovePage()**?

```
;;;  1052               if( MovePage( len ) == FALSE ) {
0xc00000000c0c55c0:2 <TMF::PrintLog(char*)+0x32>:  adds         r44=0x480,r32;;
0xc00000000c0c55d0:0 <TMF::PrintLog(char*)+0x40>:  ld8          r43=[ret2]
0xc00000000c0c55d0:1 <TMF::PrintLog(char*)+0x41>:  (p6)  st4  [r35]=ret3
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Paul R: the core was generated in HP-UX B.11.31 U ia64.

Comment: OK - you should probably tag this as `ia64` and/or `itanium` to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Assigning a value to `r44` almost certainly does *not* cause a crash.

Please edit your question to supply output from GDB `where`, `disas` and `info registers` commands. Then we should be able to tell you precisely where it crashed (and possibly why).